# Xcode 6 storyboard screen size wrong in iPhone5s(iOS 7) but not (iOS 8)

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode6

I created a new project with xcode 6.0.1 using swift and set deployment target to iOS 7.0.

The screen size is wrong for iPhone 5s in iOS7 - it shouldn't have any black spaces.

[image: blacks spaces in iPhone 5S]

Comment: saranpol would you mind to change the accepted answer in order to help the users? thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In new Xcode 6 projects, you don't have these Default-568h@2x.png images.

Do the next steps to fix it:

1) Open your Images.xcassets and look for **LaunchImage**. It is probably missing.

[image: Images.xcassets]

2) In this case, click on + (located at the bottom) and click on New Launch Image.

3) Select your project target and open Build Settings tab. Look for "Asset Catalog Compiler - Options" section and then "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name", if it is empty type LaunchImage.

[image: Asset Catalog Compiler]

Voila!

Comment: This one should be the corect answear

Comment: thanks for your answer..whats the reason behind this,.please and thanks..!

Comment: another solution is to set the "Launch Screen File" in project target -> General -> App icons and launch images

Answer (score 13):

Try using Default-568h@2x.png image as splash.

[image: Default-568h@2x.png]

Comment: Yes, this is the right trick to do. The only thing is, in Xcode 6, I did not see the file auto generated as before. I had to manually copy the Default-568h@2x from some old project.

Answer (score 10):

1. Project Properties -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Click (Use Asset Catalog)
2. Pop-up -> Click (Migrate)
3. Delete (Launch Screen File)

Finish!!!

Comment: follow this step it works for me with Xcode 6.1.1, thanks @EralpB

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 7, make sure in addition to what's been said about adding a LaunchImage you also add this entry in the plist file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this won't help much, but I have exactly the same problem and found this link. Maybe it helps you, I coulnt find the answer:

[Xcode 6 Storyboard the wrong size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105357/xcode-6-storyboard-the-wrong-size)

Answer (score 1):

put Default-568h@2x to your app bundle with dimension 640x1136. You can assign launch images using xcode catalog assets alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

Under project properties, ensure you are using the "asset catalog" for launch images. I found my project was using a custom location by default. By switching over to "Use Asset Catalog", the top/bottom black margin went away.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem in **XCode8**. I figured it out that **Launch Screen File** was not set.

Go to :
*project Properties -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images*

Click on drop down and select
**Main.storyboard**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - so easy - but I was overlooking it. I tried to add a splash screen - wouldn't work and when I deleted all references, when I would do a build my view was distorted and not all the objects were showing - even after a restore from the previous day's backup. Used your suggestion - back to normal. Sad how complicated Apple makes what should be an easy feature to add - and keeps changing it from one Xcode version to the next. Not everyone sits in front of Xcode 6 days a week...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved when you add the Splash screens for Defualt@2x.png and Defualt-568h@2x.png