# Launch Screen Comes Smaller in iPhone 5., App Size Smaller than screen

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-5, screen-size, application-size

i use xcode 6 for development. 
In my app launch screen is smaller than screen size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? The question is not clear...

Comment: Is the entire app running in the smaller compatibility mode or is the issue just for the launch image?

Comment: Your launch images may be wrong, this is should do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945194/xcode-6-storyboard-screen-size-wrong-in-iphone5sios-7-but-not-ios-8