# How to make fullscreen in simulator

Tags: ios

I don't know how to make it run full screen, I've already turned on `Use Auto Layout` and `Use Size Classes`, but didn't work.

[image]

But when I build, the simulator look like this:

[image]

The top part and the bottom part are black. Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated: Follow the solution in this link in comment, but doesn't work:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add launch images of 640 X 1136....

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945194/xcode-6-storyboard-screen-size-wrong-in-iphone5sios-7-but-not-ios-8

Comment: This is because you have not added Launch Image source or Launch Screen Fille in Project Targets-> General.

Comment: I do the same but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the update question.

Comment: have you added image with this naming convention Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: How to do that, I don't know, can you explain clearly.

Comment: Please share image of your target's general tab... where you can select Launch Screen File

Comment: Please check the update again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

1) As you did't added images in the Launch Image Assets your view is not showing property
2)At first you need to rename images in following format

Default-568h@2x~iphone.png - 2x for 5s,5

Default@2x~iphone.png - 2x for 6

Default@3x~iphone.png -3x  for 6+

2) Now just drag and drop your images for the specific resolutions you want to support and set the created LaunchImage asset as your source.[image]

3)[Add launch Image documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you delete the **Images.xcassets** -> **LaunchImage**. Than create a new LaunchImage **Taget** -> **General** -> **App Icon and Launch Images** choose **Launch Images Source**
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing, Stop ur simulator, then restart it and then when your simulator is running go to hardware on the menu and try to scale down to 50% or either 33%. this should work
 If not 
select your view controller then go to the Attributes inspector and then go to size and select 4.7 inch and then try to run it again.

All the best

Comment: I try to quit the simulator, and run it again, but didn't work.