# XCode 6.0 storyboard - can't place elements to fit all device screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I haven't been using XCode for a while (in fact, since 4.0).
Today, I tried placing some elements, let's say, in the example - three centered labels.
I remember it usually centered for all devices universally (iPad, iPhone 4, iPhone 5 etc).
But now it seems to mess up.

I have noticed that I can change the Simulated Metrics Size to "4 inch" for example, and it solves it just for the iPhone 5/5S. But I want my application to fit universally, and I remember I did it before.

Is there any setting that I'm missing?

Here's an example:

(1) The storyboard placement and Simulated Metrics settings in my XCode, perfectly centered labe
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7jpR.png

(2) The final result, simulated on an iPhone 5 (same goes for my personal iPhone 5S device):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lUc3.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to set the constraints, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24105407/691626

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto layout. Set the width, height, leading alignment and center x alignment for each label. Your constraints should look something like this...

[image]

And then it will show in the simulator like this...

[image]