# Xcode 6.1.1 StoryBoard Size

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

Good morning,

I am new to Xcode and am learning to create iOS applications.

When I open a single view application and click on main.storyboard, my size is w Any h Any. When I decide to add a label and run the iOS simulator (iPhone 6 or iPhone 5S), the label appears somewhere else.

This is really frustrating and I have tried many approaches such as disabling use size classes, changing the storyboard size by clicking the w Any h Any button, and even messing with the constraints as mentioned here: [Xcode 6 Storyboard the wrong size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105357/xcode-6-storyboard-the-wrong-size)

I am really trying to continue with this but I have seem to hit a wall for a couple of hours now, if someone could shed some light to why I am messing this up, that would be amazing.

EDIT: How can I get it to be a "normal" sized iPhone, such as the iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on the w Any h Any to change it to a normal iphone size by mousing over the squares and reading which devices they encompass.

You are going to have to use constraints though in order to make anything go where you want it to, I really didn't want to learn them but I couldn't do without them now: they are very useful.

**EDIT**

Constraints are simple in concept but can be tricky in certain situations:

For any view to have valid constraints that work correctly, it needs to know what the size of the view is and its position in it's "parent container" which is just whatever view or viewController it is inside of.

The little |-O-| shaped button and its neighboring buttons next to "w Any h Any" give you options for positioning and sizing the view. So if you click on a view and then click on that square button in the middle, check the width, height boxes and click the left and top lines in that top positioning thing with sizes in it like so:

[image: adding constraints]

Then click on add 4 constraints. You will notice blue lines appear around your view saying that it can properly put it where it needs to go when running the app. If there is any orange or red that means there are conflicting constraints on the view.

[image: good constraints]

Sometimes that can mean you put to many constraints (more than you need) and you just need  to delete them in size inspector tab. But more often than not, if that doesn't fix it, I've noticed that I usually have a neighboring view that isn't properly "constrained" and is actually the cause for the other views problems.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how to use the constraints? I have tried and am not sure what to do. For example, say I picked a size of w Compact h Any

Comment: @Jessica I updated my answer with a small tutorial, there are more detailed ones online that explain more of the different constraints you can add to a view.

Comment: Alright, and I have to do this for EVERY view? Also when you say "view", you are referring to the label correct? Why not just call it a label?

Comment: Also as advice, should I work in the Any size and just add constraints? Or should I work in let's say a more appropriate size for iPhone's and add constraints from there? (Assuming I am making applications for iPhone's only right now, since I need to start somewhere)

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the label, but even the label is a subclass of UIView, Most of the controls you can drag and drop in interface builder are UIViews. You will have to do this for every view, but it becomes second nature pretty quick. And yes I use any size for designing it in general, then when it doesn't show up right on a certain device, I change the class to match that device then add or rearrange the constraints for that specific device class.

Comment: It also helps to change the size class if you want to see how the constraints are affecting different widths and heights without running it on that device or simulator.

Comment: Amazing, I followed your steps exactly, and when I run the damn simulator the text is still placed to the right of the screen... I clicked the 2 boxes (middle one already checked), and I selected the left and top lines. Adding a total of 4 constraints, I ran the simulator and have the exact same problem that I started with... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to bring to a stackoverflow chat, so go to this webpage and I'll try to help http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/xcode+chat?password=

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get it to be a "normal" sized iPhone, such as the iPhone 5s

You don't. The view controller's main view will be resized correctly when the app runs (on a device or in the simulator), as appropriate for the device type and other aspects of its surroundings.

*Your* job is to use auto layout so that *no matter how* the view is resized, its subviews (labels and buttons and so forth) will look good. That is what auto layout is *for* - it's to help you compensate for the fact that you have no idea what the real size of this view will be at runtime.